# How to set FormGroup values from another component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to set `FormGroup` value and access method of a component from another component in Angular 8. But calling method gives me `undefined`.

First component looks below.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  onLogin() {
    console.error(this.loginForm.value);
  }

}
```

Second component looks below.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from '../modules/account/login/login/login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome',
  templateUrl: './welcome.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./welcome.component.css']
})
export class WelcomeComponent implements  OnInit {
   @ViewChild(LoginComponent, { static: false })
   private loginC: LoginComponent;

  constructor( ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginC.loginForm.controls['email'].setValue('myEmail@domain.com');
    this.loginC.loginForm.controls['password'].setValue('myPassword');
    this.loginC.onLogin();
  }

}
```

My `LoginComponent` will have its own html and user access. In some special cases, I want to dynamically log in with custom values.

What else am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to perform the login call in a service and inject it in login component.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   ...
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService) { }

  onLogin() {
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value);
  }
}
```

then you can inject AuthService in any component or service and perform a manual login.

Comment: authService.login() is there in a service but how do I set values to this.loginForm.value. In fact loginForm have approx 20 properties so I do not want redeclare it.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good way of doing things. Are you sure that LoginComponent is not be destroyed when you attempt to perform manual login? If it's not destroyed and the @ViewChild returns correct reference then you can try the patchValue method. e.g. this.loginC.loginForm.patchValue({email: "abc",password: "123", ... })

Comment: LogonComponent is not destroyed. Even tried with patchValue too.

Comment: I still don't get why you have to do it this way. Even if your form has 20 inputs, you would still have to submit it with http call. I'm suggesting to extract that http call into a service and then you can call that service from anywhere else without depending on LoginComponent.

Comment: Actually, i have 100 users list in json and I want every user to login once. This is repeated activity. I created a loginService and I consume in loginComponent. loginComponent have 20 properties with defined validations.  My json is not validated that's why I would like re use loginComponent's form Group and submit every users data from loginComponent to loginService.

Comment: Angular FormGroup creates a simple javascript object as value. If you copy that object key by key correctly, there's no reason why it wouldn't work without the formGroup.